# How to show this Fibonacci identity? $f_{3n}=f^3_{n+1} + f^3_n - f^3_{n-1}$

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

I already know that $f_{n+m}=f_{n-1}f_m + f_nf_{m+1}$.

By letting $m=n$ it immediately follows that $f_{2n}=f_{n}(f_{n+1} + f_{n-1})$ and from that we get $f_{2n}=f^2_{n+1} - f^2_{n-1}$.

From this one should be able to see that $f_{3n}=f^3_{n+1} + f^3_n - f^3_{n-1}$, but I somehow can't figure it out.

Comment: Have you ever come across [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/a/6/0/a6083f85f39b468210f5715a8e30d572.png) representation of the Fibonacci numbers? I suspect it might provide a neat route to the solution.

Comment: Yeah, I know this one. Thanks for bringing it to my attention again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$\begin{align}f_{n+2n}&=f_{n-1}f_{2n}+f_nf_{n+1+n}\\
&=f_{n-1}(f_{n+1}^2-f_{n-1}^2)+f_n(f_{n}f_{n}+f_{n+1}f_{n+1})\\
&=f_{n-1}f_{n+1}^2-f_{n-1}^3+f_n^3+f_nf_{n+1}^2\\
&=(f_{n-1}+f_n)f_{n+1}^2-f_{n-1}^3+f_n^3\\
&=f_{n+1}^3-f_{n-1}^3+f_n^3\end{align} $$